How can we rename a tag?
The tag [pair-trading] has been created. I think it should be renamed [pairs-trading]. I know it is not very important but I find it slightly annoying.

Good point. I have merged these tags.

Do you need to be some kind of admin to do this ? I do not mind helping for minor maintenance.

@BlueTrin Moderator, yes.
